# OdbcDataAdapter Fill function not giving output if we show record from temperary table (#temp)

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

**I am using below code to retrive data from table using stored procedure :**

```
 Dim Pars(0) As OdbcParameter
 Pars(0) = New OdbcParameter("@UserID", OdbcType.VarChar)
 Pars(0).Value = usrid
 Pars(0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
 Dim UserTbl As DataTable = Nothing
 UserTbl = DBAccess.RunStoredProcedureDttbl("USP_GET_Data", Pars)
```

**Below function giving output in SYSBASE database but no record found in case of SQL SERVER DB**

```
Public Overloads Shared Function RunStoredProcedureDttbl(ByVal ProcedureName As String, ByVal pars() As OdbcParameter) As DataTable
        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            If Cmd.Parameters.Count > 0 Then
                Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            End If
            Con = New OdbcConnection(ConnectionString)
            Con.Open()
            dt.Clear()
            Cmd = New OdbcCommand(" {call " & ProcedureName & PrepareParameters(pars), Con)
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            For Each par As OdbcParameter In pars
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(par)
            Next
            Cmd.Connection = Con
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            OdbcAd = New OdbcDataAdapter(Cmd)

            OdbcAd.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As OdbcException
            Throw New ArgumentException(ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException("DAL\\DrDAL\\RunStoredProcedureWithParameters\\ " & ex.Message)
        Finally

            Con.Dispose()
            DisposeObjects()

        End Try
    End Function
```

**I tried below function working fine in both database**

```
Public Overloads Shared Function RunStoredProcedureDtOut(ByVal ProcedureName As String, ByVal pars() As OdbcParameter) As DataTable
        Try

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            If Cmd.Parameters.Count > 0 Then

                Cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            End If
            Cmd = New OdbcCommand(" {call " & ProcedureName & PrepareParameters(pars), Con)
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            For Each par As OdbcParameter In pars

                Cmd.Parameters.Add(par)

            Next

            OdbcDr = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(OdbcDr)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As OdbcException

            Throw New ArgumentException(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException("DAL\\DrDAL\\RunStoredProcedureWithParameters\\ " & ex.Message)

        Finally
            OdbcDr.Close()
            Con.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Function
```

**What is reason? Why "OdbcAd.Fill(dt)" not working in SQL SERVER DB ?**

**Code for  PrepareParameters**

```
Private Shared Function PrepareParameters(ByVal pars() As OdbcParameter) As String
    Try
        Dim s As String = " (?"
        Dim i As Byte = 0
        If pars.Length >= 2 Then
            For i = 0 To pars.Length - 2
                s = s + ",?"
            Next i
        End If
        s = s + ")}"
        Return s
    Catch ex As OdbcException
        Throw New ArgumentException(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ArgumentException("PrepareParameters\\ " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

**First function showing records when I remove temperary table from Store procedure.If I store data in temperary table (#temp)  and then display record.It result into zero record.
Can anyone tell me reason ?**

Comment: Can we see the code of `PrepareParameters(pars)` ?

Comment: @Steve : Code added check